# C++ Mortgage payment calculator formula

Tags: c++

I've been working on a mortgage calculator for my C++ class. However, I am stuck.

I got the following formula off of Nerdwallet and tried to implement it in my program:

M = P [ i(1 + i)^n ] / [ (1 + i)^n – 1]

M=mortgage payment

P=Principal

i=interest

n=number of payments

Here's the code that I am currently using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int years, homePrice, creditScore, totalPayments;
    float rate, mortgageTotal, monthlyPayment;
    cout << "What is the price of the home that you are looking to mortgage?\n";
    cin >> homePrice; //Assigns the variable homePrice to a value

    cout << "What is your credit score?\n";
    cin >> creditScore; //Assigns the creditScore variable a value
    cout << "Would you prefer a 15 year or 30 year mortgage? Please type 15 or 30.\n";
    cin >> years;

if ( years = 15 ) //If input is 15 year it will go down this logical path
    {
        if (creditScore >=760) //If their credit rating is equal to or more than 760, their rate will be .043 also nested if.
            { 
                rate = .043;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 4.3%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 700) //If their credit rating is equal to or more than 700, their rate will be .0455
            {
                rate = .0455;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 4.55%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 660) //If their credit rating is equal to or more than 660, their rate will be .048
            {
                rate = .048;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 4.8%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 620) //If their credit rating is equal to or more than 620, their rate will be .058
            {
                rate = .058;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 5.8%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 580) //If their credit rating is equal to or more than 580, their rate will be .0655
            {
                rate = .0655;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 6.55%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 500) //If their credit rating is equal to or more than 500, their rate will be .083
            {
                rate = .083;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 8.3%\n";
            }
    }
else if ( years=30 ) 
    {
        if (creditScore >= 760)
            {
                rate=.043;
                cout <<"Your interest rate is 4.3%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 700)
            {
                rate=.0455;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 4.55%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 660)
            {
                rate=.048;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 4.8%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 620)
            {
                rate=.058;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 5.8%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 580)
            {
                rate=.0655;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 6.55%\n";
            }
        else if (creditScore >= 500)
            {
                rate=.083;
                cout << "Your interest rate is 8.3%\n";
            }
    }
    totalPayments = years * 12;
    monthlyPayment = homePrice * [[rate * (1 + rate)pow(totalPayments)] / [(1 + rate)pow(totalPayments) - 1]];
    mortgageTotal = monthlyPayment * totalPayments;

    cout << "Your mortgage will cost approximately " << mortgageTotal << " and your monthly payment will be " << monthlyPayment << endl;
return 0;
```

}

However, when I go to compile it, I get the following errors:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgzyv.png)

I just don't understand the errors and why they are there.

If someone could help me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: `monthlyPayment = homePrice * [[rate ...` you seem to be using `[]`s in place of `()`s, they are not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

While your math formula uses both `[]`s and `()`s for grouping expressions, only `()`s can be used in such a way in C++.

`pow` is a function call, not an in-place operator like you seem to be using it. It needs to look like `pow(1 + rate, totalPayments)`.

Your `if`s also are doing assignments (`=`) instead of comparisons (`==`). As it is, your code will only follow the first `if` because it is setting `years` to 15.

Comment: Kmdreko, so I changed the [] to () and changed the if statements to == instead of =.

It'll compile and run now. However, I firmly believe that the calculation that it's giving me is wrong.

Comment: what values are you getting wrong results for? does working it out manually give different results than your program?

Answer (score 0):

Your mortgage formula seems wrong. Try this

```
monthlyPayment = homePrice * ((rate * pow(1 + rate, totalPayments)) /  
(pow(1.00 + rate, totalPayments) - 1));
```